# How can you have a persistent checkbox that opens or closes a div each time it is checked in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

So when the page loads it will check the checkbox and do a function if called.  Once it loads the page, then the checkbox is not responsive and won't do anything after that point.  The first drop down will load the `test1.php` but the check boxes in `test1.php` don't do anything.

How do you make a checkbox responsive within the second page that is loaded?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

$('#modal123').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
    $('#allsites').on('change', function() {
        //alert("test");
    $( "#test1" ).load( "test1.php" );  

    });

$("#California :checked").on("change", function(){
    $( "#test1" ).load( "test2.php" );  
});



  }) //end modal
}); //end script
```

HTML:

```
<body> 
<div><a href="#"
class='btn btn-default' 
role='button' 
data-toggle='modal' 
data-target='#modal123'
>modal1</a>
</div>
                                                    <div id='integrate_employee_popup1'></div>
                       <!-- modal pop up for [view audits] button -->
<div class="modal fade" style="z-index:10000" id="modal123" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">View car</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <select id="allsites">
                  <option value="Site1">Site1</option>
                  <option value="Site2">Site2</option>
                </select> 

                <div id="test1"></div>  

                <div id="test2"></div>  
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            <form method = "POST">
                <input type="button" id="yes_delete" value="Yes " name="view_audits_delete" />
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
            </form> 
                </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

test1.php

```
<?php print '<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="detailsgiven" id="California" >California
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="detailsgiven" id="Georgia" >Georgia
  <br>
</form>'; ?>
```

test2.php

```
<?php print "Test2"; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to create event listeners for elements that don't exist yet

```
$(document).on("change", "#California", function(){
    if(this.checked){
       $( "#test1" ).load( "test2.php" );  
    }
});
```

Comment: I would have never thought of that, but it makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

This code below should do what you need it to. The problem is you're adding the listener when the page loads, before an option is selected and the checkboxes created. The elements need to exist when you bind an event to them. So include this code **after** you load the checkboxes into the DOM. You can add a callback to your load event to be fired after inserting the elements.

```
$( "#test1" ).load( "test1.php", function() {
    //After loading test1.php and the elements are inserted into the dom, attach the listener
    $('#California').on('click', function(e) {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            alert('checked');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: He's adding the element asynchronously through .load() so there's not way to ensure this runs after the element is loaded if you don't use delegated events

Comment: *"after you load"* requires use of load callback that OP doesn't have

Comment: @Cruiser that's not really true... `load()` has  success callback argument available as well as promise callbacks

Comment: true, but like you said, OP isn't using them

Comment: @Cruiser but answer can be updated to include them...it's just lacking that detail

Comment: that's why i didn't down vote it. ..and apparently i can't edit my first comment

Comment: Thanks guys, I've updated the answer to include a callback.

Comment: That callback is really handy

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use delegated events as when your jquery script loads, the #California element doesn't exist yet. You can do this by adding a selector to an .on() event handler:

```
$('#test1').on('click','#California',function(){
   // code that happens when you click
});
```

You can use other events than just the 'click' event as well. See the Jquery API docs here for more info: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: My answer is nearly identicle as the one you accepted.